# Train a neural network to detect the most frequent input

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

Is there any neural network architecture that can predict the most frequent number in the input? I am aware that this problem can be solved using a classic programming language like python, I'm interested to know the characteristic of this problem in the neural network world.

Let assume the input is an array of `N` integers in `[0, M)` and output is a one-hot encoding of size `N` that represents the most frequent numbers. For example, if the input is `x = [4,0,4,3,2,4]` then the output would be `y = [1,0,1,0,0,1]` (`N=6` and `M=5`).

I have tried a two-layered network which works fine for small inputs, but it cannot scale well for larger inputs, e.g., `N=25` and `M=10`. I suspect that it memorizes all the domains.

Any idea on solving this problem for larger size, or anything related to tackle this family of problems is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try two things (units & epochs):

1) Play with size of units, for task `x = [4,0,4,3,2,4]` it is going to be enough to use one layer with 3 units:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3-9, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, input_dim=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.linear))
```

2) And also for task like this, I can advise just set a lot of epochs, because it is specific task and your NN need time to set all parameters. But also do not set a lot of units, because your NN can often go another way.

My advice:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3-100, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, input_dim=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3-100, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.linear))
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.mse,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=1,
          epochs=1-infinity,
          verbose=1)
```

- activation relu (units will not die)
- batch_size 1 -> for this task you need to relie on all inputs

So, start to play with one epochs and find out best accuracy and watch on LOSS (when your LOSS going to be small, your accuracy will increase rapidly) depending on how much units. When find best amount of units, set as many epochs as you have time (try 10, then 50...).

Hope, it will help somehow. Good luck!